# How could I run my purchased apps in the iOS Simulator?

Tags: iphone, app-store, ios-simulator

I wonder if it's possible to run a purchased and downloaded application in iOS Simulator? I am building a website and it's far to easy and quick testing in the simulator but has some disadvantages.
The app I want to run in the simulator is the Atomic Web Browser. It's got a pretty good source viewer (and I need it because my ajax scripts).

So my question is: how could I run my purchased apps in the iOS Simulator?

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, there is at least no legal way. (You need a source viewer although you are writing the code?)

Comment: The iOS simulator is a simulator and not a emulator and will not be able to run applications built for ARM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apparently](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=run+purchased+apps+in+simulator) [not](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1617459?start=0&tstart=0).

Simulator apps are compiled for i386 architecture, whereas iPhone apps are compiled for ARM. The simulator can't run apps compiled for ARM, so you can't run purchased apps, or any apps from the store, in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way, since the app purchased and downloaded from the App Store are ARM CPU based apps and the simulator is i386 CPU based.